# Gas estimation failed on run in rinkeby network

Tags: solidity, web3.py, gas-limit, rinkeby, brownie

ValueError: Gas estimation failed: 'invalid opcode: opcode 0xfe not defined'. This transaction will likely revert. If you wish to broadcast, you must set the gas limit manually. Could someone please help me with what have I done by mistake?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you include the code that causes the problem as text? That error is usually triggered by a fault in the contract code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on a dev net (do not do this on main-net):

```
def fund_with_link...
....
# arbitrary gasLimit amount...
    myAwesomeGasLimit = 50000 
    funding_tx = link_token.transfer(
                      contract_address, 
                      amount, 
                      {"from": account, "gasLimit": myAwesomeGasLimit}
                 )
....
```

[further info](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/114500/brownie-rinkeby-valueerror-gas-estimation-failed)